# Selenium Select value from dropdown not working in Edge/Safari but works in other browsers

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, microsoft-edge

I have a page that has a dropdown where you can switch between different options and it loads a new page which I am trying to automate the testing of. However, on Safari/Edge the select function never changes the option. I have tried using .click methods as well as executing a script to change the attribute on the element to 'selected'. In Chrome/FF/IE this all works fine. I wrapped the function in a try catch and there aren't any errors present, it just doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def test_safari_edge(self):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(self.tp.org_dropdown_options)
        )
        select = Select(self.tp.find_element_by(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.js-org-switcher.org-name-wrapper > select'))
        select.select_by_value('myorg')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running tests on different OS and testing different browsers on each one, but only I've found this issue using Safari Webdriver.

Current Selenium version: 3.6

After searching and trying some tips like updating the WebKit of MacOS or using Select() in several ways, I've decided to use JavaScript.

```
@when(u'I set the example dropdown to "{option}"') 
def step_impl(context, option):
    selenium = context.selenium

    selenium.execute_script(u"""                                                                                              
        $("select[name='dropdown']").val('{0}');                                                                    
    """.format(option));
```

Works perfectly in all browsers waiting for a WebDriver solution.